# Is an async do while loop permitted?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following loop:

```
do {
  await future;
} while (condition);
```

Is `await` in `do while` loops permitted?

Comment: Hi, yes it is possible if your function is async, but what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes for sure, that's an example

```dart
void test()async{
  
  int x =0;
  do {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds:50));
    print(x);
    x++;
  } while (x<5);
}
```